In ReactJs how do I add hash or nounces into third party libraries in order to remove unsafe-inline CSP
I am trying to remove the unsafe-inline for style-src but issue is coming from the third party libraries that adds <style> tags and the amount is insane.
example of libraries: videojs, react semantic ui and many others.
What can I do add hash or nounce into them?

